# Sencha Touch 2- How to get index of sub row in itemTpl?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I am new to Snecha so please bear my non technical description.

MyView.js

```
itemTpl: [
'<div class="pb10 font-90">{associationDiplayText}</div>' +
                '<div style="float:left">' +
                '<div class="bold font-90"><b>{name}</b></div>' +
                '<div class="font-90">{address1}</div>' +
                '<div class="font-90">{address2}</div>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div style="display:block;" class="fltR" id="displayIcon">' +
                '<a href="#" class="grayBtnCls fltL" style="margin:0 10px"><span id="phoneId" class="phoneIcon"></span></a>' +
                '<a href="#" class="grayBtnCls fltL" style="margin:0"><span id="emailId" class="emailIcon"></span></a>' +
                '<div class="clr"></div>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div class="clr"></div>' +
                '<div  style="display:none" id="display" class="mt15 mb10">'+

                    '<tpl for="contacts">', 
                        '<div style="float:left">' +
                        '<div class="font-50">{contactTypeText}:</div>' +
                        '<div class="font-50">{name}</div>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<div class="fltR" id="innerdisplay">' +
                            '<a href="#" class="grayBtnCls fltL" style="margin:0 10px"><span id="contactphone" class="phoneIcon"></span></a>' +
                            '<a href="#" class="grayBtnCls fltL" style="margin:0"><span id="contactemail" class="emailIcon"></span></a>' +
                            '<input type="hidden" value="{#}" id="hiddenindex" />'+
                            '<div class="clr"></div>' +
                        '</div>'+
                        '<div class="clr"></div>' + 
                    '</tpl>', 

                '</div>'+
                '<div align="center"><a href="#" ><span id="moreLess" class="moreLinkCls">{moreDetail}</a></div>'
    ]
```

Controller.js In onItemTap I am doing following

```
onItemTapListView: function(view, itemIndex, target, record, event, eOptions) {
     if(event.getTarget("#contactphone.phoneIcon")){    
            var contactRecord = record.data.contacts[itemIndex];
     }
```

The problem is that when i click the first row it gives itemIndex = 0 which is what I expect but it also gives the same result when I click on phoneIcon from contact list which has around 10,15 items. what I need is to get the index on which contact item user has clicked.

Thanks in Anticipation

Answer (score 0):

Each instance of the 1st-level record object will be set to a different row no mather what it contains.
ST wont ever know on which contact is the user tapping because the entire row is a single unit.

I know the UI would be different, but my recommendation is to go with a [Nested List](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.dataview.NestedList) approach.

regards-

Comment: It is requirement that I have to show the contact list with in each row.So cant move anyway. Found a workaround but not happy with that.
Also want to know how to get current row's div and child div of the row ?

Comment: @AsifJutt: The third parameter you r receiving (target) is the element that has been tapped. You can do 'target.element.dom' to get the html node.